# What's the significance of DNA replication (S phase) before Meiosis?

Tags: dna, meiosis, cell-cycle

From what I'm able to understand, Meiosis should end up with haploid cells with chromosomes having single chromatids (I don't know why it's necessary, but alright)

I understand that meiosis has a slightly different interphase than in case of mitosis, with basically no G₂ phase.

My question is then, why does the DNA / Chromosome replicate / duplicate before meiosis?

If DNA doesn't replicate before meiosis (during S phase of interphase), meiosis 1 can still occur. But this time we'll directly end up with haploid cells with single chromatid chromosomes.

Does double division in meiosis has a biological significance? Does it ensure better (less erroneous) division or something similar?

Possible (Unhelpful) duplicate questions:

1. [Why there is replication of DNA before meiosis?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65693/why-there-is-replication-of-dna-before-meiosis)
2. [What is the purpose of two cell divisions in meiosis?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55832/what-is-the-purpose-of-two-cell-divisions-in-meiosis)